# Devexpress xtrareport character spacing

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport, character-spacing

How to add **character spacing** in **devexpress xtrareport** in lable.

I am trying to search on their site but they answer that they do not support it.

Here is the link: [Click Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S90507/xrlabel-ability-to-specify-character-spacing)

I want this for cheque date print.
If anyone has any answer please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the XRLabel report control doesn't provide a way to specify the character spacing, but you can try using the [XRCharacterComb](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRCharacterComb.class) report control instead. Does this help?